# use Img source with php variable

Tags: php

I want to use some thumbshots generated images inside a WP loop, and the code looks like this:

```
if (!$thumbnail && wpbdp_get_option('use-default-picture'))
    $thumbnail = 'http://images.thumbshots.com/image.aspx?cid=xxxxxxxxxx&v=1&w=283&url=URLHERE';
```

URLHERE is generated by this:

How to replace the URLHERE thing with the output (outputs and URL) of:

```
<?php echo wpbusdirman_the_listing_meta('single'); ?>
```

I am very bad at php.

Thanks,

Comment: What does *doesn't work* means?

Comment: may need to assign the output to a variable, or at least figure out what that is doing/returning.  `$output=wpbusdirman_the_listing_meta('single');  echo $output;`

Comment: Dave, that is returning a URL.

Comment: I edited the question to understand better my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL encode the returned value!! You're putting a URL into a URL- if you don't URLEncode it, you're asking for more than a little trouble.
I believe it's as simple as:

```
<?php echo urlencode(wpbusdirman_the_listing_meta('single')); ?>
```

:)

Comment: Thanks a lot but how do I put that in my code:  if (!$thumbnail && wpbdp_get_option('use-default-picture'))
        $thumbnail = 'http://images.thumbshots.com/image.aspx?cid=xxxxxxxx&v=1&w=283&url=http://www.yahoo.com';  - instead oh the yahoo thingy.

Comment: You could literally insert the code snippet I posted where your "URLHERE" is, or, alternatively (and much cleaner) you could assign it to a variable and insert the variable:
<?
$imageURL = urlencode(wpbusdirman_the_listing_meta('single'));

And then
$thumbnail = 'http://images.thumbshots.com/image.aspx?cid=xxxxxxxxxx&v=1&w=283&url=$imageURL';

Comment: This is what I did and somehow it doesn't work..     if (!$thumbnail && wpbdp_get_option('use-default-picture'))
     $imageURL = urlencode(wpbusdirman_the_listing_meta('single'));
        $thumbnail = 'http://images.thumbshots.com/image.aspx?cid=HIPFHapOLHw%3d&v=1&w=120&url=$imageURL';

Comment: If you're putting a variable inside a string and expect it to be read as a variable, the string must use double quotes. using single quotes will insert the literal value (in this case $imageURL) .
You want to use "images.......$imageURL" instead of 'images....$imageURL'.

Answer (score 1):

```
$thumbnail = 'http://images.thumbshots.com/image.aspx?cid=HIPFHapOLHw%3d&v=1&w=283&url='.urlencode(wpbusdirman_the_listing_meta('single'));
```

Comment: It looks like a typo- he put a "$" on the urlencode. Try removing it?