# PHP variable in an ing src

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [use Img source with php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645493/use-img-source-with-php-variable)

I have a small issue here, i am sure it is an easy one but I am terribad at php.

I am using a WP plugin which pulls at a certain moment the first image attached to a post, in my case, a picture that user uploads upon a business submission (it is a business directory plugin).

I don't want that, instead, I want thumbshots.com generated thumbnails. My code looks like this (I replaced the defaul value of *$thumbnail*):

```
if (!$thumbnail && wpbdp_get_option('use-default-picture'))

$thumbnail = 'http://images.thumbshots.com/image.aspx?cid=HIPFHapOLHw%3d&v=1&w=283&url=URLHERE';
```

Now, instead of URLHERE, should be placed an actual URL, the listing´s one. Which is created by this:

```
<?php echo wpbusdirman_the_listing_meta('single'); ?>
```

How do I do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Didn't you just ask this exact same question?

Comment: @andrewsi It is an exact duplicate, as a matter of fact, it is the same person asking.

Comment: Please do not open duplicate question. If you feel you have something to add, you can always [edit] it. If you don't get enough attention, make a constructive edit which will bump your question to the top, or gain enough reputation for a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties)

Answer (score 0):

```
$thumbnail = 'http://images.thumbshots.com/image.aspx?cid=HIPFHapOLHw%3d&v=1&w=283&url=' . wpbusdirman_the_listing_meta('single');
```

or

```
$thumbnail = "http://images.thumbshots.com/image.aspx?cid=HIPFHapOLHw%3d&v=1&w=283&url=$wpbusdirman_the_listing_meta('single');
```

?

READ: http://phphowto.blogspot.com/2006/12/concatenate-strings.html